# NormalModuleReplacementPlugin is not working for replacing node_modules scss file with another scss file in assets

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

`_bg-theme.scss` file is installed in `node_modules` after adding a package in package.json

I am trying to replace `node_modules` scss file  with the scss file(_bg-theme.scss) we added in assets folder `bg-theme.scss` .

I am using `webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` but its not working.

## webpack.common.js

```
 plugins: [
     new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
          /\/node_modules\/@bg-file-menu\/core\/dist\/styles\/mixins\/_bg-theme.scss/,
          '../../../src/web/assets/styles/bg-theme.scss',
        )
  ]
```

What is the correct way to fix this. Any suggestion or solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The second path (your assets file) is relative to the first.  So you'd have to go a few more levels up.

```
plugins: [
 new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /\/node_modules\/@bg-file-menu\/core\/dist\/styles\/mixins\/_bg-theme.scss/,
      '../../../../../../../src/web/assets/styles/bg-theme.scss',
    )
```

]

Comment: This solution didnt worked. The path is correct in question and that is not the issue. NormalModuleReplacementPlugin may be not working with scss files here. Maybe some another solution needed here for above question.

Comment: Try `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/web/assets/styles/bg-theme.scss')` instead of just the path as second argument.

Comment: No, still its not working. I think this may not be correct way to replace scss files like we do  for js files using NormalModuleReplacementPlugin.